# How to create a user entered query search

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to create a report that produces rentals for tools, as its required to be interactive, i'd like the user to be able to enter the partial name of a tool or full name to bring up all the rentals for that tool.

```
TTITLE CENTER ==================== SKIP 1-
CENTER 'U  T O O L' skip 1-
CENTER ==================== SKIP 1 - 
LEFT 'Rental Report ' SKIP 1 -
LEFT ============ SKIP 2-
RIGHT 'Page:' -
FORMAT 999 SQL.PNO SKIP 2 

set pagesize 50

column MEMBERNAME HEADING 'Member Name'  format a20
column TOTAL HEADING 'Total Cost' format L9,999.99

compute sum label 'Total Cost: ' of TOTAL on MEMBERNAME
Break on Rental_ID on Member_ID on MEMBERNAME on Member_ID on Tel SKIP 1

select Member.Member_ID, SUBSTR(Member.FName,0,10) || SUBSTR(' ',0,10) ||
SUBSTR(Member.SName,0,15) as MEMBERNAME, Member.Tel,
Rental.Rental_ID,
Tool.Name, 
Rental.DateOut,
Rental.DateIn,
Rental_Line.Qty,
Rental_Line.Price,
Rental_Line.Qty*Rental_Line.Price as TOTAL
from Rental_Line
INNER JOIN Rental
on Rental.Rental_ID = Rental_Line.Rental_ID
INNER JOIN Member
on Rental.Member_ID = Member.Member_ID
INNER JOIN Tool_Instance
on Rental_Line.Tool_Instance_ID = Tool_Instance.Tool_Instance_ID
INNER JOIN Tool
on Tool_Instance.Tool_ID = Tool.Tool_ID
where Tool.Name = '%&_%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a stored procedure that takes in a parameter, something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rentalReport(toolName IN varchar)
AS
--your query here
where Tool.Name = toolName
```

not sure about the exact syntax, haven't used Oracle db..

More info:
http://www.ics.com/files/docs/dx/tut6.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`ACCEPT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12005.htm#sthref1777) command - it enables user to interact with your script. Like this:

```
09:26:55 SYSTEM@dwal> create table t (key number primary key, value varchar2(10));

Table created.

09:27:15 SYSTEM@dwal> insert into t values (1, 'abcdef');

1 row created.

09:27:20 SYSTEM@dwal> insert into t values (2, 'ghijkl');

1 row created.

09:27:32 SYSTEM@dwal> commit;

Commit complete.

09:28:48 SYSTEM@dwal> accept search_str char prompt "enter parameter > ";
enter parameter > def
09:30:01 SYSTEM@dwal> select * from t where value like '%&search_str.%';

       KEY VALUE
---------- ----------
         1 abcdef
```